# After a restart, preventing Group Policy Update from updating the registry values

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, group-policy

My machine is part of a corporate domain and I have local admin rights on this machine.

Due to the GPs applied, I was not able to change my wallpaper. So I did a GPResult /v and figured out the problem was 2 registry entries in the following directory:

KeyName:     Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\Wallpaper
                Value:       67, 0, 58, 0
                State:       Enabled

KeyName:     Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\WallpaperStyle
                Value:       50, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

I deleted both the above entries, and now I am able to change the wallpaper. However, these entries are restored in the registry whenever I restart my machine. And once again, the wallpaper cannot be set manually.

**Question:**
Is there a way I can prevent the Group Policy from updating the above two registry entries on every restart? I don't want to disable all other GP updates pushed by my company.
PS: I have local admin rights.

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of Group Policy is to enable your network administrator to configure settings on company computers and *have those settings enforced* (hence the name Group **Policy**).

If you ask your domain administrator nicely, he can exempt just your computer from this policy quite simply. Or perhaps you could help him see the folly in locking down your wallpaper and remove the policy from the domain entirely!

Comment: thanks Twisty. I understand the point that you are trying to make, however it is not always possible to approach the domain admin for such things. Any technical workaround for this problem is greatly appreciated

Comment: "ask nicely and he can exempt your computer..." A well-reasoned argument is probably not going to be effective against an admin (or corporate policy) that locks down something as trivial as wallpaper.

Comment: You could be correct. But consider other scenarios: Maybe the policy was put into place long ago by an Admin no longer with the company and the new one isn't aware of the policy's impact on users. Your don't know until you ask, and asking nicely will be the most effective way to do so.